# can use dbscan on 1D array?

Tags: r, dbscan

I want to find the clusters on an array. I tried this code:

```
mydata <- C(0.067238904, -0.102679881, 0.01940899, -0.131117488, -0.214517613, 0.157258923, 0.036706008, 0.016978233, 0.116067734, 4.743973742, 14.45681545, 19.79653307, 19.63551697, 14.75640964, 14.49508407, 29.57162957, 34.35154035, 24.5891771, 19.5566106, 19.77786917, 19.48045239, 19.39253524, 19.6119075, 19.37288854, 14.46814558, 5.045143817, -0.179989144, 0.028726364, 5.095571357, 9.611555878, 9.782350203, 9.816313554, 4.669270539, 0.168666591, 0.145820734, 0.098501045, 0.227520096, 9.570195928, 19.3275607, 9.893992329, -0.183070026, -0.234127009, 0.009692396, -0.043350227, 0.086534462, 4.940506347, 9.682493476, 9.6797441, 9.912886934, 4.702649696, 0.126017184, 0.067977594, 9.808998855, 19.74575552, 9.908506244, 0.078706378, 9.901372568, 19.48938819, 19.75414373, 19.30717806, 9.715180742, 4.753063059, 14.84621102, 24.5142621, 24.22609497, 9.819711948, 4.860427965, 19.62910875, 29.48940595, 24.46262038, 24.39358348, 29.31943171, 19.67473155, 14.5374882, 29.39737594, 34.29607172, 29.09359081, 29.21900907, 24.33754818, 19.62927235, 24.50864647, 29.55191414, 29.15532645, 29.23586306, 19.69262392, 14.88864931, 29.31430615, 39.08977936, 34.37013456, 29.28457452, 29.09823037, 24.59405531, 19.72552198, 24.28197776, 34.20368783, 38.96958544, 29.5214294, 14.42708676, 19.5855616, 29.42845242, 24.59078733, 29.32780403, 34.19078719, 19.59049443, 14.89861361, 24.50865539, 29.34039008, 24.27815921, 14.78998033, 14.58721547, 29.52443582, 29.56073152, 19.30874611, 19.30472237, 9.912708087, 9.741318791, 29.23817381, 29.24338455, 14.66415896, 14.82204758, 24.32628072, 24.36577297, 19.5338725, 19.51281431, 19.57161821, 19.73853609, 19.5444779, 29.51936609, 29.52085292, 9.840828548, 9.95537852, 19.3793856, 19.70600151, 29.4517574, 29.56955801, 14.7456921, 19.53452657, 24.66074808, 19.7398255, 24.30808533, 19.70857809, 9.841699767, 24.28906266, 33.98590267, 24.36929409, 19.34572709, 9.626587523, 9.854661829, 24.54829185, 19.61713169, 19.73651064, 34.29485221, 24.63946819, 9.679601386, 19.60449283, 24.45146344, 19.30179531, 19.72184805, 14.43924964, 19.42170776, 29.0984513, 19.78242071, 14.57892748, 19.39415279, 14.88312006, 19.55170865)
mydata <- matrix(mydata, nrow = 1)

library("dbscan")

db <- dbscan(mydata, eps = 1)
```

¿Do dbscan needs 2D data?

- The code "works", but I get zero clusters: db.cluster=0
- I get no error.
- How do I set the parameter eps? in general I can't predict that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the format of your matrix. You have 1 row and 166 columns. But dbscan will treat each *row* as a data point, so it looks like you have 1 point in 166 dimensional space. You want

```
mydata <- matrix(mydata, ncol = 1)
db <- dbscan(mydata, eps = 1)
DBSCAN clustering for 166 objects.
Parameters: eps = 1, minPts = 5
The clustering contains 8 cluster(s) and 2 noise points.

 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 2 23  8 17 42 25  7 21 21
```

Comment: Thank you G5W. To thank, have a reward: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AezzZkJ8sZA

Comment: This is the actual answer to the problem. The others are useful comments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

But the result is essentially an extremely primitive variant of **Kernel Density Estimation**, and the usual libraries will be much slower hang necessary.

I'd rather use KDE.

Comment: rather late now, and not sure if you have quit already, but would you mind elaborating on your point? or any links that might give more details on this?

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn's implementation of DBSCAN doesn't take advantage of some significant speed-ups that are possible with a 1D space. For example, distances can be calculated via bisecting sorted arrays rather than computing full distance matrices.

I wrote a small package that has the same interface (nearly) as sklearn's DBSCAN but is significantly faster. Check it out [here](https://github.com/d-chambers/dbscan1d).